# Some floating point values should sum to zero in PHP, but do not

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

```
<?php
$a = 128.3;
$b = 140.7;
$c = 12.4;
echo $a-$b+$c;   //2.30926389122E-14
?>
```

it will display "2.30926389122E-14"

Why it is not zero?

```
<?php
$a = 112.7;
$b = 125.2;
$c = 12.5;
echo $a-$b+$c;   //0
?>
```

What's the difference between them?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: Well, for most calculations `0.0000000000000230926389122` *is* zero, i.e., the impact will be negligible :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) answers this better than I could:

> Floating point numbers have limited
>   precision. Although it depends on the
>   system, PHP typically uses the IEEE
>   754 double precision format, which
>   will give a maximum relative error due
>   to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16.
>   Non elementary arithmetic operations
>   may give larger errors, and, of
>   course, error progragation must be
>   considered when several operations are
>   compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that
>   are exactly representable as floating
>   point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or
>   0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point
>   numbers in base 2, which is used
>   internally, no matter the size of the
>   mantissa. Hence, they cannot be
>   converted into their internal binary
>   counterparts without a small loss of
>   precision. This can lead to confusing
>   results: for example,
>   floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually
>   return 7 instead of the expected 8,
>   since the internal representation will
>   be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results
>   to the last digit, and never compare
>   floating point numbers for equality.
>   If higher precision is necessary, the
>   arbitrary precision math functions and
>   gmp functions are available.

**Edit:** Your question title asked how to fix. It's simple... rounding. `$val = round($val, 2);`

Comment: Regarding the fix: Alternatively, use an [epsilon value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) when doing comparisons, e.g., `abs($myVal) < MY_EPSILON_VALUE`.

Answer (score 12):

It's *not* a bug, it's a very-well documented phenomenon of IEEE754 floating point standards.

There are a limited number of bits to represent floating point numbers and there are, let me see if I can remember, yes, an *infinite* number of real numbers between any two distinct numbers.

That means you cannot represent all real numbers but have to provide approximations.

The way to *fix* it is to not assume that numbers can be represented exactly. You should detect if a number is *close enough* to zero rather than equal to zero, and you can do this by choosing a suitably small error value based on your numbers and operation.

Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) as a detailed treatise (warning, this may be a bit of a hard read), or [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) has a gentler introduction as well as a link to the [BC Math package](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) for PHP (arbitrary precision arithmetic) which may be of use to you.